# HTML/CSS/JS World map with simple animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I need a simple visualization for events occurring over the world -- a 2d image of a world map, and a way to display visual alarms when events happen at a [lat, lng].

This is not core functionality. I'm willing to look into libraries or engines, but I don't want to add a huge learning overhead.

What's the simplest way of doing it?

Comment: Are you using Google Maps? This will help https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays

Comment: I would use Google Maps to place markers because lat/lng isn't a simple grid system. Overlay it with a world map image of your own if you prefer.

Comment: I'm looking into that right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had good experiences with google's visualization api. They have a map that will allow you to do what your looking for. It's also pretty well documented and plenty of resources online.

You can take a look at their maps documentation here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map

Comment: Google's data visualization is the way to go, also take a look at [Geocharts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart).